# how to print the value inside a variable in cmakelist.txt

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm using CMake for my recent project and I want to confirm that the right path is set

```
set(_protobuf_include_path -I . -I ${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I used `message` to check the value of `_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR` but not printing anything in terminal

```
message( STATUS ${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR} ) # no output for this
```

My intention is to build Grpc1.14.1, bit it is having dependency with protobuf, so I downloaded protobuf 3.6.01 and both grpc and protobuf kept under same directory (`home/user/src`).

While building I got this error

```
google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
```

So I opened `protobuff.cmake` in directory `gRPC/cmake` and changed the protobuf root path

```
if(NOT PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR)
  #set(PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/protobuf)
  set(PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR ../../ThirdParty/protobuf)
[...]
```

After doing this, I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Try adding quotes. `message([<mode>] "message to display" ...)` from [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html#command:message). Also add some prompt in case of an empty value

Comment: message(STATUS "message to display" ${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR})

Comment: not getting anyoutput

Comment: "but not printing anything in terminal" - So the variable's value is empty (or the variable is not set at all).

Comment: @Sijith I think you need to provide the location of protobuf from the commandline using `-DPROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR=[...]`, instead of setting a relative path. From what I gather the location is under `/home/user/src/`. Otherwise, protobuf is included as a git submodule in grpc, so you could do `git submodule init && git submodule update thirdpart/protobuf/` and continue from there with the initial unmodified CMake file.

Answer (score 0):

First, something a bit irrelevant to the question, but related to [modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/) techniques and usage.

In order to set the include path, it is preferred to use the [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) command, e.g.

```
target_include_directories(mytarget 
  PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  PUBLIC ${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )
```

Now, for the actual question, it would help if you could show the actual setting of `${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR}`, (is it through the command line via `-D) options?)but you could print it like this:

```
message(STATUS "include dir: ${_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

I'm suspecting spurious whitespace or something along those lines in the actual variable contents.

Comment: if(NOT PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR)
    #set(PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/protobuf)
    set(PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR ../../ThirdParty/protobuf)
 message(STATUS "message11" ${PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR})
  endif()

Comment: if(EXISTS "${PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR}/cmake/CMakeLists.txt")
    set(_gRPC_PROTOBUF_WELLKNOWN_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROTOBUF_ROOT_DIR}/src")

Comment: @Sijith Please amend the question by [edit]ing it; don't add extensive code in the comments.